# 18.04 - custom keyboard shortcut to adjust volume does not work (instead mutes)

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a problem after upgrading my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS (18.04.3) with my custom keyboard shortcut for volume control.
I want those shortcuts because my keyboard has no specific media keys.

my setup:

- system settings -> Devices -> Keyboard -> Custom Shortcuts
- add shortcuts with this configuration:

  - Volume up: amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
  - Volume down: amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-

problem description:

- pressing the assigned keyboard shortcut **will lower the volume to 0**. But the system icon (the speaker which will change the appearance according to the volume level) does **not** show the symbol for **muted** audio.
- using the commands (for example amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+) in bash will result in the expected behavior:

  - volume changes by 5%
- My configuration worked on Ubuntu 16.04

Do you have any idea what i am doing wrong or how to solve this?

Any help is highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found that in Ubuntu 18.04 it's necessary to escape the - and + character.

So for volume up:

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%%+
```

and volume down:

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%%-
```